# Airpush banner add - failed to instantiate

Tags: android, xml, instantiation, airpush

In short, after adding Airpush banner ad to XML (I followed the [wiki](http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Standard_SDK_1.0#Installation_Instructions)), I get following error upon startup of the application:

> Failed to inflate android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line
>   119: Error inflating class

I've added Airpush banner add inside layout XML like this:

```
<com.kuepm.ixmvw184326.AdView
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ap:animation="fade"
    ap:banner_type="inappad"
    ap:placementType="interstitial"
    ap:test_mode="true"
    ap:canShowMR="false"
    />
```

Instantiation problem is exposed also after switching to live preview of XML:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.kuepm.ixmvw184326.AdView

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of invested time I found out *something* was wrong with Google Play Services library setup.  I didn't find out what exactly, but after removing it and adding it again, the problem with instantiation is gone.

Comment: Don't use airpush!!! They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)